# OpenCL generate SHA-256 hash

Tags: opencl, gpu

I need help with OpenCL.

The task is as follows:

There is an input parameter of type string. It is necessary to generate a SHA-256 hash using the resources of the video card.

It is necessary to create a cycle to select a hash. Each time add some postfix to the original string.
Result*Hash should start with 5 zeros "00000 ...".

For example, the entrance. parameter: "strela".
SHA-256: "7d7ceecdee08ea1c0ac46b27657a79395af36526b3214b59a92f8351ccf8f762"

Next, you need to add a postfix. For example, "strela1"
Here the hash will be: a2afd15651f44f19f3e4e216bf3ead22d5f5937e9f9dc250382ff1f764ba219f

then continue to add the postfix until the resulting hash begins to start with "00000.."

It is necessary to use all the cores of the video card, i.e. use parallelization. Each core will use its postfix.
As soon as some kernel computes the hash we need, interrupt all calculations on the cores and display the hash we need.

Source:

**main.cpp**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "sha256.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include < string.h > 



void crypt_and_print(char input[])
{
  char result[65];
  char diff[65] = "00000";
  char *istr;
  char  buffer2[20];
  int temp;

  char str2[20];



  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {

      char string[] = "1qqq";

      sprintf(buffer2, "%d", i);
      temp = 8 - strlen(buffer2);
      str2[0] = '\0';
      while (strlen(str2) != temp)
          strcat(str2, "0");
      strcat(str2, buffer2);
      strcat(string, str2);
      sha256_crypt(string, result);

      istr = strstr(result, diff);


      if (istr != NULL) {
          printf(istr);
          break;
      }


  }

}

int main()
{
  char result[65];

  sha256_init(2048);

  crypt_and_print((char*)"");

}
```

**sha256.c**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "sha256.h"

static cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
static cl_device_id device_id = NULL;  
static cl_uint ret_num_devices;
static cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
static cl_context context;

static cl_int ret;

static char* source_str;
static size_t source_size;

static cl_program program;
static cl_kernel kernel;
static cl_command_queue command_queue;


static cl_mem pinned_saved_keys, pinned_partial_hashes, buffer_out, buffer_keys, data_info;
static cl_uint *partial_hashes;
static cl_uint *res_hashes;
static char *saved_plain;
static unsigned int datai[3];
static int have_full_hashes;

static size_t kpc = 4;

static size_t global_work_size=3;
static size_t local_work_size=1;
static size_t string_len;

void load_source();
void createDevice();
void createkernel();
void create_clobj();

void crypt_all();


void sha256_init(size_t user_kpc)
{
    kpc = user_kpc;
    load_source();
    createDevice();
    createkernel();
    create_clobj();
}

void sha256_crypt(char input[], char* output)
{

    int i;
    string_len = strlen(input);
    global_work_size = 3;
    datai[0] = SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH;
    datai[1] = global_work_size;
    datai[2] = string_len;
    memcpy(saved_plain, input, string_len+1);

    crypt_all();


    for(i=0; i<SHA256_RESULT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        sprintf(output+i*8,"%08x", partial_hashes[i]);
    }
    printf("'%s':\n%s\n", input, output);


}

void crypt_all()
{
    //printf("%s\n",saved_plain);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, data_info, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) * 3, datai, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, buffer_keys, CL_TRUE, 0, SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH * kpc, saved_plain, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // printf("%s\n",buffer_keys);
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    // read back partial hashes
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, buffer_out, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE, partial_hashes, 0, NULL, NULL);
    have_full_hashes = 0;
}

void load_source()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/sha256.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );


}

void create_clobj(){
    pinned_saved_keys = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, (SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH)*kpc, NULL, &ret);
    saved_plain = (char*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue, pinned_saved_keys, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE | CL_MAP_READ, 0, (SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH)*kpc, 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    memset(saved_plain, 0, SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH * kpc);
    res_hashes = (cl_uint *)malloc(sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE);
    memset(res_hashes, 0, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE);
    pinned_partial_hashes = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE, NULL, &ret);
    partial_hashes = (cl_uint *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue, pinned_partial_hashes, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    memset(partial_hashes, 0, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE);

    buffer_keys = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, (SHA256_PLAINTEXT_LENGTH) * kpc, NULL, &ret);
    buffer_out = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_uint) * SHA256_RESULT_SIZE, NULL, &ret);
    data_info = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(unsigned int) * 3, NULL, &ret);

    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(data_info), (void *) &data_info);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(buffer_keys), (void *) &buffer_keys);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(buffer_out), (void *) &buffer_out);
}

void createDevice()
{
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
}

void createkernel()
{
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "sha256_crypt_kernel", &ret);
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
}
```

**sha256.cl**

```
#ifndef uint32_t
#define uint32_t unsigned int
#endif

#define H0 0x6a09e667
#define H1 0xbb67ae85
#define H2 0x3c6ef372
#define H3 0xa54ff53a
#define H4 0x510e527f
#define H5 0x9b05688c
#define H6 0x1f83d9ab
#define H7 0x5be0cd19


uint rotr(uint x, int n) {
  if (n < 32) return (x >> n) | (x << (32 - n));
  return x;
}

uint ch(uint x, uint y, uint z) {
  return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);
}

uint maj(uint x, uint y, uint z) {
  return (x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z);
}

uint sigma0(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 2) ^ rotr(x, 13) ^ rotr(x, 22);
}

uint sigma1(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 6) ^ rotr(x, 11) ^ rotr(x, 25);
}

uint gamma0(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 7) ^ rotr(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3);
}

uint gamma1(uint x) {
  return rotr(x, 17) ^ rotr(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10);
}



__kernel void sha256_crypt_kernel(__global uint *data_info,__global char *plain_key,  __global uint *digest){
  int t, gid, msg_pad;
  int stop, mmod;
  uint i, ulen, item, total;
  uint W[80], temp, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,T1,T2;
  uint num_keys = data_info[1];
  int current_pad;

 //printf(get_global_id(0));

  uint K[64]={
0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

  msg_pad=0;

  ulen = data_info[2];
  total = ulen%64>=56?2:1 + ulen/64;

  //printf("ulen: %u total:%u\n", ulen, total);

  digest[0] = H0;
  digest[1] = H1;
  digest[2] = H2;
  digest[3] = H3;
  digest[4] = H4;
  digest[5] = H5;
  digest[6] = H6;
  digest[7] = H7;
  for(item=0; item<total; item++)
  {

    A = digest[0];
    B = digest[1];
    C = digest[2];
    D = digest[3];
    E = digest[4];
    F = digest[5];
    G = digest[6];
    H = digest[7];

#pragma unroll
    for (t = 0; t < 80; t++){
    W[t] = 0x00000000;
    }
    msg_pad=item*64;
    if(ulen > msg_pad)
    {
      current_pad = (ulen-msg_pad)>64?64:(ulen-msg_pad);
    }
    else
    {
      current_pad =-1;    
    }

   // printf("current_pad: %d\n",current_pad);
    if(current_pad>0)
    {
      i=current_pad;

      stop =  i/4;
  //    printf("i:%d, stop: %d msg_pad:%d\n",i,stop, msg_pad);
      for (t = 0 ; t < stop+get_global_id(0) ; t++){
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 2]) << 8;
        W[t] |= (uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 3];
   //     printf("W[%u]: %u\n",t,W[t]);
      }
      mmod = i % 4;
      if ( mmod == 3){
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 2]) << 8;
        W[t] |=  ((uchar) 0x80) ;
      } else if (mmod == 2) {
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |= ((uchar) plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4 + 1]) << 16;
        W[t] |=  0x8000 ;
      } else if (mmod == 1) {
        W[t] = ((uchar)  plain_key[msg_pad + t * 4]) << 24;
        W[t] |=  0x800000 ;
      } else /*if (mmod == 0)*/ {
        W[t] =  0x80000000 ;
      }

      if (current_pad<56)
      {
        W[15] =  ulen*8 ;
   //     printf("ulen avlue 2 :w[15] :%u\n", W[15]);
      }
    }
    else if(current_pad <0)
    {
      if( ulen%64==0)
        W[0]=0x80000000;
      W[15]=ulen*8;
      //printf("ulen avlue 3 :w[15] :%u\n", W[15]);
    }

    for (t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
      if (t >= 16)
        W[t] = gamma1(W[t - 2]) + W[t - 7] + gamma0(W[t - 15]) + W[t - 16];
      T1 = H + sigma1(E) + ch(E, F, G) + K[t] + W[t];
      T2 = sigma0(A) + maj(A, B, C);
      H = G; G = F; F = E; E = D + T1; D = C; C = B; B = A; A = T1 + T2;
    }
    digest[0] += A;
    digest[1] += B;
    digest[2] += C;
    digest[3] += D;
    digest[4] += E;
    digest[5] += F;
    digest[6] += G;
    digest[7] += H;


  }


  printf("hi");


}
```

How can i use here paralelism (all GPU  cores) to calculate needed hash code?

Is it real to do task like this using OPENCL ?

Comment: You should be able to find code performing this on Github. What are your requirements? which GPU, how big is your input data. Wondering what you are trying to achieve with the code.

Comment: FYI this is not the place to solicit for paid work. I removed that from your question accordingly.